# Identity matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, server, identity

We use a server in our university to make our codes, and this one is tho check if a matrix is an identity matrix, so I wrote this code, and in VSCode and Python Tutor it seems right, but on the server it says it is wrong for the list [[0,0],[0,0]] (I've used this exact same list in VSCode and the result was False, but on the server it says that my code is returning "True")

Here´s the code

```
def eh_identidade(l):
t = len(l) - 1
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    lista = l[i]
    if 1 not in lista:
        return False
    ind = lista.index(1)
    if ind == i:
        i += 1
        del lista[ind]
        if any(lista) == 1:
            return False
    else:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: `if not 1 in ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to quickly generate an indentity matrix of any size, then you can compare it to your input.

```py
import numpy as np
def is_identity(M):
  M = np.array(M)
  dimension = len(M)
  identity = np.identity(dimension).tolist()
  return (M==identity).all() and M.shape==identity.shape
```

(To check whether or not it is a square, we can compare the shape of the two matricies.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the matrix is square, you can just directly compare it with an identity matrix using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def is_identity(matrix):
    return np.allclose(matrix, np.eye(len(matrix)))
```

Note that `np.allclose` allows you to process an input matrix of floats and get the correct result. If you're not sure it's square (or if it could be ragged), you can check using

```
def is_identity(matrix):
    nrows = len(matrix)
    if not all(len(row) == nrows for row in matrix):
        return False
    return np.allclose(matrix, np.eye(len(matrix)))
```

Comment: @OctopuSS7 `matrix` doesn't need to be an `ndarray`.